# How to Create 40% Off Promo for a Certain Category of Products?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, promotions

I'm trying to create a promo for 40% off on products in a certain category. I'm having difficulty limiting the discount to the categories I want. When I apply the coupon to the cart, the discount is being applied to all products in the cart, not just the categories I want. Here is a screenshot of my setup, I'm using Magento 1.9.3.4. The categories I want the discount to apply to are 165, 166, 167, 168, 169.

[image: 40% Off Supplements (Does not Include Samples/Stacks)]

Comment: You seem applied it correctly. A product can be added to multiple categories. So from the cart, check each product in the admin if it belongs to any of that categories.

Comment: @Ner I checked the products and made sure they were categorized properly. Is there any way I can specify in the rule to NOT include certain categories?

Comment: did you try to flush all caches and reindex all?

Comment: @Ner yeah I did that several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration its correct but you have only one rule there, try to change from ANY to ALL.
Has you have only one rule there and the ANY and ALL applies only for the rules and not for the info inside the rule, it will work with ALL.
I tried with ALL and ANY with your configuration and it works perfectly with both cases.
You shoud have something on the products that its causing this issue, some bad configuration on categories or something else.

Comment: thank you , you were correct. there was an issue with the products I was trying to ban (bundle) containing products from the group I was trying to put the discount on. I think a customization is needed for this workaround. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can include all the other categories except : `165, 166, 167, 168, 169.` using **Category  is no**t option as below :

[image]